# How to import an existing Aurora Serverless cluster in a AWS CDK project/stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have a need to "detect" Aurora Serverless cluster in order to use it in an AWS Cloud Development Kit project. The cluster has to be created externally in order to ease the management.

How can I import the existing Aurora Serverless cluster by its ARN or name into AWS CDK code (similarly to `Ec2.Vpc.fromLookup` CDK call)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use the static [`fromServerlessClusterAttributes`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-rds.ServerlessCluster.html#static-fromwbrserverlesswbrclusterwbrattributesscope-id-attrsspan-classapi-icon-api-icon-experimental-titlethis-api-element-is-experimental-it-may-change-without-noticespan) method?

```js
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import * as rds from '@aws-cdk/aws-rds';

export class AuroraServerlessStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const myServerlessCluster = rds.ServerlessCluster.fromServerlessClusterAttributes(
      this, "ExistingCluster", {
        clusterIdentifier: "cluster-id-for-existing-cluster"
      }
    )
  }
}
```